# How to change GWT.xml with maven profile by a GWT project

Tags: gwt, maven, profile

Currently, i am working on a gwt-maven project. As every GWT project, it has the following gwt.xml

```
<module rename-to='myProject'>
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
   .
   .    
   ...
```

I created another gwt.xml to set configuration for continous integration. (as defined [here](http://jgonian.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/efficient-gwt-development-swap-your-gwt-xml-with-maven/).)

```
<module rename-to='myProject'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.myCompany.myProject' />
   .
   .    
   ...
```

and here is my pom to manage the profiles and change the gwt.xml.

```
<profile>
  <id>ci</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
                  <module>com.myCompany.myProject</module>
                  <style>OBF</style>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>

</profile>
```

If i try to package the project with profile ci (mvn package -Pci), i get the following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.3.0-1:compile (default) on project MyProject: GWT Module com.myCompany.myProject not found in project sources or resources. -> [Help 1]
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If your Module file is located at src/main/resources/com/myCompany/ the compiler should find your Module. Can you confirm that?

By the way, GWT module names start with a capital letter by convention.

Comment: I have only one modul/one project. My target is only to change some gwt configuration on Jenkins with using profile.

Comment: I followed the procedure described in the link you posted and it worked fine for me. Both of my modules are located at the same place... my development module inherits from the production module and overrides some properties to make compiling faster. It works nicely!!! I've got to thank you for posting that link! I was tired of modifying properties depending on whether I wanted a dev or prod version! I hope it works for you too... make sure there's no typos anywhere in your files... it could be just that!

Comment: Confirming that the solution provided in the link works for me as well in 2k20 :)